# Add animated drawable as logo in Toolbar Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

is it possible to add an icon in Toolbar that can animate? I have an animation-list xml and I want to use it as icon in my toolbar instead of a normal drawable.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.animated_icon);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

My drawable:

```
<animation-list android:oneshot="true"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:duration="250" android:drawable="@drawable/first_case" />
    <item android:duration="250" android:drawable="@drawable/second_case" />
    <item android:duration="250" android:drawable="@drawable/third_case" />
</animation-list>
```

I tried with `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.animated_icon);`
But this does not animate at all. Is this going on the wrong path? Thank you.

Comment: Do you still need to start the animation in java?

Comment: I have added: toolbar.animate(); but nothing changed.

Comment: Is my question that bad that i got a negative vote? If it's unimportant I will just delete it, no need to make "un-useful" content.